# Find number(s) from current excel file in other excel and copy the row to current excel file

Tags: excel, vba, copy, find, range

I have some numbers in column H from the range H4 to H40. The range and numbers may vary, sometimes there could be 1 or two number sometimes it may be 5, 7, 10, 15. etc.

I want to find those numbers in another excel file and copy that entire row in current sheet. The numbers will be on different rows but I want to copy only those rows which has the number.

Is there any VBA code to do this? The numbers are of around 10 digits or less.

Comment: Could you please provide with the VBA code for the above? With elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that you have two files in this situation `File-1` and `File-2`
See screenshot below.  Assume that File-1 has all the information you need
[image: File-1]

Let us say that File-2 has your numbers ( I have assumed **UNIQUE** 10 digit numbers)
[image]

Now if you have to bring in the row content of say the first row (which would be `TOM`, `15`, `M`, you should use the `VLOOKUP` command.

In the cell adjacent to `123456789` enter the following formula
`=VLOOKUP(B3,[Book1]Sheet1!$B$3:$E$9,2,0)`

If we breakdown this formula
`VLOOKUP` - This is the lookup function
`B3`      - The location(cell address) of the data `123456789` 
`[Book1]Sheet1!$B$3:$E$9`  - This has two parts.

- The `[Book1]` refers to the name of File-1 in which there is data.
- The `Sheet1!$B$3:$E$9` - refers to the Sheet name ( Sheet 1 in this case) and the range in which the data is present (starting from `B3` to `E9`)

`2` refers to the column number from the first cell in the range
`0` means exact match.

In the end, my File-2 will look like this with the formula.
[image]

Comment: I want to copy entire row. Vlookup returns the value of one cell only. and also i want it to do for 50 to 60 files so its not possible for me to put in the formula for each sheet. can you suggest any other way?